# Checking previous created NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, core-data, time

I have an `NSManagedObject`-subclass Event - with some event data in user's life, also it have an `NSNumber`-type field called `time`, with unix timestamp representation of when this event had place. So typically user will have many Events. In showing current `Event` data through `tableView` I also need to show some data from previous by date `Event`. Does `Core Data` have some marks when objects created, that I can directly know what exactly `Event` was created before current, or do I need to fetch with predicate by value of `time`?

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch objects from CoreData, and if you're using `UITableView` it's a good practice to use `NSFetchedResultsController`, which has a lot of good features for presentation data in `UITableView`